# Why doesn't this work when I add it to the current sed being run?

Tags: bash, sed, osx

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
(empty) 
str
int
int
```

If I add this `s/^/\</g` to my current sed (making it `'s/\&/\</g;s/\</\
/g;s/^/\</g'`) this is the output.

```
< ##only this line gets a < 
str
int
int
```

But if I make a new line, and type the entire command like `sed -i '' 's/^/\</g' *.p*`, this is the output

```
< 
<str
<int
<int
```

What difference does it make?

Comment: What is "your current `sed`"?

Comment: @MichaelHomer the current sed process being run. Like this `sed 's/something/something/g;s/somethingelse/somethingelse/g'`. Instead of   `sed 's/something/something/g'`
and `sed 's/somethingelse/somethingelse/g'` Just one sed and one command doing two things, under there it's two sed doing one thing each instead. That's what I meant in the question, using a `;` instead of running two different `sed`s.

Comment: @don_crissti I didn't think it was relevant but sure.

Comment: What @MichaelHomer said. Can you reformat your question so we see: the full sed command, and the resulting output for the first case. Because I have indeed encountered situations where prior sed options and arguments can affect later sed commands, so if possible please include the whole command, thanks.

Comment: @user454038 both of these things are in my question.

Comment: Remember you have two sample results 1. the example where line 1 has `<`, and 2. the example where all lines have `<`. While I do see you list the full sed that results in #2, but where is the full sed that creates #1?

Comment: @user454038 It's right there `'s/\&/\</g;s/\</\
/g;s/^/\</g'`. Makes only the top (empty) line get a `<`.

Answer (score 0):

The difference is to do with input and output. In the first case you're inserting a `\n`ewline, yes, but you're still operating on the same pattern space - and so the `^` head of pattern space remains where it is, even though it contains embedded newlines - which you insert for each occurrence of `<`.

But in the second case you're working with a new `sed` and reading the last `sed`s output as input - and so all of those newlines it injected the first go-round count as separate input lines now, and each gets its own `^`head of pattern space.

```
echo ..... | 
sed 's/./&\
/g;s/^/sed1/' |
sed 's/^/sed2/'
```

---

```
sed2sed1.
sed2.
sed2.
sed2.
sed2.
sed2
```

---

By the way...

```
sed 's/&/</g;s/</\
/g'
```

...is probably more easily written...

```
sed 'y/&</\n\n/'
```

...but if you just want to stick a newline behind every `[&<]` and to substitute every `&` for `<` then you could do:

```
sed 's/[&<]/<\
/g'
```

...but your output doesn't match your input at all...

Answer (score 0):

```
sed 'expression;expression'
```

is the same as

```
sed -e 'expression' -e 'expression'
```

which, in a few *simple* cases, is the same as

```
sed -e 'expression' | sed -e 'expression'
```

---

In your case (from what I can see), you are trying to change all `&` into `<`. Then all `<` into newlines, and then finally you add `<` to the beginning of lines:

```
s/\&/\</g;s/\</\
/g;s/^/\</g
```

With the given input, this `sed` script will do the following with BSD `sed`:

```
$ sed -f script.sed file
<
<

<

<
```

Or, with GNU `sed`:

```
$ gsed -f script.sed file
<
<
str
<
int
<
int
```

Why is this?

1. First of all, there are no `&` in the file (the `\` in front of `&` may additionally be dropped), so the first expression is a no-op.
2. The second expression matches `\<` which is a (beginning of) word boundary. To be honest, I'm a bit baffled by why the text is removed by BSD `sed` (I will see if this is a bug in OpenBSD `sed`). So this inserts a newline at the beginning of each word of the example file.
3. The third expression, still operating on the same (now modified) line of input, inserts a `<` at the start of the line.

In contrast to this, the single expression `s/^/\</g` (in which the `\` in front of `<` and the `g` modifier is not needed) will just insert a `<` at the start of each line.

---

Follow-up: It has been confirmed that there was a bug in the `sed` implementation on OpenBSD 6.1-stable concerning prepending a string to a line that starts with an inserted newline. A patch has been submitted.